# Rails 4 ActiveRecord multiple queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use rails 4.2.5.
I have some sort of N+1 problem in this code

`seats=SeatItem.where(:b => hall.id).all
    seats.each do |seat|
      arr << Ticket.new(:a => seat.id)
    end
      Ticket.import arr`

Problem of this code is that i have this in log

`MIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE "seat_item_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "seat_item_types".* FROM "seat_item_types"  WHERE`

Why `:all` method does not load all in memory and how fix it?
Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `:all` is the problem. Notice that the repeated SQL query is identical and that it's fetching rows from `seat_item_types` not `seat_items`. My guess is that you have a before/after hook or some other code that is being triggered by `Ticket.new` or `Ticket.import` that is accessing `seat_item_type`.

Comment: Your asnwer really very helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use eager_load for solve N + 1 query problem

use includes method like this

```
clients = Client.includes(:address).limit(10)

clients.each do |client|
  puts client.address.postcode
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

But first of all, I think you define associations on SeatItem and Ticket
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html